# Creating a line graph (mean), arranged by facets, with standard error of mean error bars: ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, linegraph, errorbar

Hi Stack Overflow community,

I have a dataset:

```
conc branch  length stage factor
1    1000      3   573.5   e14   NRG4
2    1000      7   425.5   e14   NRG4
3608 1000     44  5032.0   P10   NRG4
3609 1000      0     0.0   P10   NRG4
```

FYI

```
> str(dframe1)
'data.frame':   3940 obs. of  5 variables:
$ conc  : Factor w/ 6 levels "0","1","10","100",..: 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...
$ branch: int  3 7 5 0 1 0 0 4 1 1 ...
$ length: num  574 426 204 0 481 ...
$ stage : Factor w/ 8 levels "e14","e16","e18",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ factor: Factor w/ 2 levels "","NRG4": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
```

I would like to create facetted line graphs, plotting the mean +/- standard error of the mean

I have tried experimenting and building a ggplot from others (here and on the web).

I have successfully used scripts that will make bargraphs this way:

```
errbar.ggplot.facets <- ggplot(dframe1, aes(x = conc, y = length))

### function to calculate the standard error of the mean
se <- function(x) sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))

### function to be applied to each panel/facet
my.fun <- function(x) {
  data.frame(ymin = mean(x) - se(x), 
         ymax = mean(x) + se(x), 
         y = mean(x))}

g.err.f <- errbar.ggplot.facets + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "bar", 
           fill = clrs.hcl(48)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.data = my.fun, geom = "linerange") + 
  facet_wrap(~ stage) +
  theme_bw()

print(g.err.f)
```

Source: http://teachpress.environmentalinformatics-marburg.de/2013/07/creating-publication-quality-graphs-in-r-7/

In fact, I have created facetted line graphs with this script:

```
 `ggplot(data=dframe1, aes(x=conc, y = length, group = stage)) + 
  geom_line() + facet_wrap(~stage)`
```

image:  postimg.org/image/ebpdc0sb7

However, I used a transformed dataset of only means, SEM in another column, but I don't know how to add them.

Given the complexity (for me) of the bargraphs + error line scripts above, I have not yet been able to integrate/synthesize these into something I need.

In this case, the colour is not important to have.

P.S. I apologise for the long thread (and perhaps the overkill on some details). This is my first online R question, so not sure of correct etiquette. Thank you all in advance for being so helpful!

Darian

Comment: Here is an image of what I have achieved:

http://postimg.org/image/ebpdc0sb7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case your dataframe has a column for the mean and the se you could do something like this:

```
library("dplyr")
library("ggplot2")

# Create a dummydataframe with columns mean and se
df <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(gear, cyl) %>%
  summarise(mean_mpg = mean(mpg), se_mpg = se(mpg))

ggplot(df, aes(x = gear, y = mean_mpg)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean_mpg - se_mpg, ymax = mean_mpg + se_mpg)) +
  facet_wrap(~cyl)
```

Comment: Beautiful, thanks, but R has given bargraphs. How can I make line graphs?

Comment: Simply change `geom_bar` to `geom_line`.